# "express doubts about" vs. "raise doubts about"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage

In a report, there is this sentence: *"we **question the rationale** behind ABCDEF..."*

Questioning something means to have doubts about it. Cambridge defines it as *"to express doubts about the value or truth of something".*

Two other phrases often used to express the same idea (i.e., to question something) are **expressed doubts** or **raised doubts**. Google returns about 110 real entries with "authors express doubts" or "authors raise doubts"; around the same number for any combination of those (e.g., authors have expressed doubts).

My sentence looks like this:

> The authors **express/raise serious doubts** about the general validity and appropriateness of ABCDEF ...

My problem is I don't see how "express" (to convey or suggest or say or show) is equivalent to "raise". I have a feeling that a situation can raise doubts, as opposed to people (authors in my case). Or, person A can raise doubts about something in the mind of person B.

Example: But defense lawyers are paid to raise doubts. The New York Times.

In my case, the authors themselves *doubt the validity of the issue* or *question the rationale*. I feel that "express" is more suitable here, but then I am told they both work equally well.

Which is the appropriate word that fits the phrase in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Cambridge Dictionary, **raise** means  *to cause to exist*. It also says that **express** means *to show a feeling, opinion, or fact*.

The difference is that raising is generally about creating something new, whereas you can express concerns about just about anything, including things that are already in the public domain.

So, I could express concerns about global warming but I could not raise them - everybody already knows about it. On the other hand I could either raise or express concerns about the possibility that a meteorite recently observed by my team  might collide with the Earth - in this case I can use **raise** because nobody else knows about the meteorite or its path.

In your case, if somebody else has already raised these doubts, you can only use **express**. If you are the first group to identify them, then you can use either **express** or **raise**.

Comment: Ah that is a very important distinction. Thanks! Also, would you agree that "raise doubts" can be used to describe a situation, where as "expressed doubts" can only be used to describe the act of showing/conveying doubt by people? Example: *His alcohol and gambling addiction raised doubts as to whether he could actually lead the team.* Here its a person's behavior/actions that is raising doubts. Compare this with: *The students expressed serious doubts about the teacher's integrity.* "Express" could not be used in the first example.

Comment: Yes, that is probably true.